# How can i create a conditional dialog that's not dismissible in the dashboard of my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, model-view-controller, dialog, widget

I have a view, dashboard.dart, and in this file i have conditional views in which i created a different file for the individual views i'm rendering.

How do i render a conditional dialog that fills the whole screen instead of a widget?

I tried creating a widget that uses showGeneralDialog and then pass the widget to my dashboard.dart file but it seem i don't know how to go about it.

I need ideas or help

I have a snippet of my dashboard.dart file which at the end checks if the user is subscribed or not:

```html
Widget content(context) {
      return Obx(() => Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 40, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.welcome +
                                  " ${user.firstName}",
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                          if (user.userType == "player")
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                CustomSnackBar().show(
                                    '${user.profileViews ?? "0"} profile views');
                              },
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  playersController.fetchPlayerInfo(
                                      context, user.id);
                                  TabRouting()
                                      .pushScreen(context, const PlayerInfo());
                                },
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                      "${dotenv.env['BACKEND_URL']}${user.photo?.replaceAll("public", "storage")}"),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                        ],
                      ),

                      ///SHOW SUBSCRIPTION STATUS
                      if (servicesController.subscription.isEmpty &&
                          !servicesController.loading &&
                          user.userType != "club_official")
                        const SubscriptionNotice(),
```

And the widget i'm returning is SubcriptionNotice().

What i'm asking is how do i show a dialog if the user is not subscribed and pass it to that condition?

If i can use a widget, how do i configure this widget?

I tried using showGeneralDialog in my SubscriptionNotice widget but i can't seem to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple switch something like

`showDialog ?? dialogWichYouWantToShow: OtherWidget`

1. You eneter this screen and will see `OtherWidget`
2. When condition `showDialog` changes (use `setState` or something) it should display `dialogWichYouWantToShow`

Comment: showGeneralDialog is quite different from showDialog?
My question is how to implement showGeneralDialog in my SubscriptionNotice widget class